# iOS cocos2d call to recognize new Orientation?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screen-orientation

Trying to figure out how to make a call to trigger a orientation notification? By this I mean I want to make a call that checks if the device's orientation has been changed (dynamically in a variable by me) and then re-orients the device based on that variable?

I tried making a call to:

```
[appDelegate.navController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
```

But it does not trigger a rotation to occur, but is working the way I want.

Comment: not certain what you mean 'trigger' ... AFAIK it is a device orientation change that triggers an orientation change. Your role is to make certain that the app is setup properly to survive a change, and to authorize orientation changes when they do happen.

Comment: By Trigger I mean activate the Orientation Change myself. Is it possible? There are many sections to my App and I want to specify the orientation on each section to make the user experience better. For example, 2 games are included which will be in landscape, whereas other portions are tables which are much better in portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around my issue by doing this:

AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (!self.lockedToOrientation) {
        // iPhone only
        NSLog(@"default portrait");
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ){
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }

    // iPad only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"lockedToOrientation");
    return self.lockedToOrientation;
}
}
```

and HomeScreen.m

```
AppController *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    const UIInterfaceOrientation ORIENTATION = appDelegate.navController.interfaceOrientation;
    appDelegate.navController.lockedToOrientation = ORIENTATION == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [appDelegate.navController presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
    [appDelegate.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Thoughts on this process? Would Apple reject? I've heard they dislike some ways of changing/forcing orientation.

Cheers.